# Google Map Android Studio LocationManager error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

Hi im trying to display a google map with locationmanager. First the default activity from map is working but when i try some of the tutorials, I always got an error on the code below. I dont know whats wrong but i followed the tutorials in some projects.

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);
```

this is my class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //To get MapFragment reference from xml layout
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //To get map object
        map = mapFragment.getMap();

       /* //to show current location in the map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/

        //To setup location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //To request location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //To clear map data
        map.clear();

        //To hold location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        //To create marker in map
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("My Location");
        //adding marker to the map
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //opening position with some zoom level in the map
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.0f));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

these are the imports in the activity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

UPDATE:
I got no error in code but when i run i got this error in logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jathniel.mydoctorfinder, PID: 1370
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method checkSelfPermission(Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Lcom/example/jathniel/mydoctorfinder/MapsActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.jathniel.mydoctorfinder.MapsActivity' appears in /data/app/com.example.jathniel.mydoctorfinder-2/base.apk)
            at com.example.jathniel.mydoctorfinder.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Tell us the errors you have.

Comment: this code locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this); @mvai

Comment: Yes, but what is wrong with it?

Comment: it says call requires permission which may be rejected by user....... @mvai

Comment: Have u import this android.location.LocationListener

Comment: api key is not the problem because i already display the map when i created a google map activity in android studio

Comment: yes ill post the imports  that i use in the activity under the code. ill update my post @MohitSuthar

Comment: i think you are using api level 23 and did you mention permissions in manifest

Comment: i posted my logcat error @RahulChaudhary

Answer (score 0):

you should check permission in manifest before location manager initialization.

```
private boolean Permission()
```

{

```
String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

}

Comment: these are my permission

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Comment: i have android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: wheres that?im beginner in android sorry